# Android: Custom ListView and Threading problem

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, youtube-api

I'm working on a small project on Android and have a serious problem with implementing some multi-threading into my solution. Below is a class that is an activity inside the tab of the main interface, which displays a custom list with pictures and data downloaded from YouTube API.

The class works fine, but it completely blocks the UI when, first the data, and then the images are being loaded from the Internet. I know I need to implement some threading and I have tried various things, but I'm not quite sure which parts of the code I have to launch as separate threads. There's also a chance there is something fundamentally wrong with my code structure.

Ideally I'd like to have the UI shown to the user immediately after the application is launched with a progress dialog on top of it, while the textual data is being loaded from YouTube. Then the user should get control of the UI, while images are being loaded in another thread in the background.

```
public class VodsActivity extends ListActivity {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;

//private Handler mHandler;
private ProgressDialog dialog;


//Generic names of custom ListView elements
private static String[] title; 
private Vector<String> detail; 
private Vector<String> status;      
private Vector<String> imgurl; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_list);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    title = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yt_channels);
    detail = new Vector<String>();
    status = new Vector<String>();
    imgurl = new Vector<String>();

    //mHandler = new Handler();

    //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(VodsActivity.this, "","Loading. Please wait...", true);          

    loadData();
    displayData();

    //dialog.dismiss();

}

private void loadData() {           
    String[] values = {"error", "error", "http://www.ephotobay.com/thumb/message-error.jpg" };

    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        values = getData(title[i]); 
        values[1] = getTodaysUploads(title[i]);
        detail.add(i, values[0]);
        status.add(i, values[1]);
        imgurl.add(i, values[2]);
    }
}

/*** This function gets total number of uploads and thumbnail url for the user from a single feed ***/
private String[] getData (String username) {
    String[] result = new String[3];
    String ytFeedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + username + "?v=2";
    InputStream inStream = null;

    try {           
        inStream = OpenHttpConnection(ytFeedUrl);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = db.parse(inStream);
        Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

        inStream.close();

        NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("entry");
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element entry = (Element) nl.item(i);
                Element thumbnail = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("media:thumbnail").item(0);
                String thumbUrl = thumbnail.getAttribute("url");
                Element feedLink = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("gd:feedLink").item(5);
                String uploads = feedLink.getAttribute("countHint");

                result[0] = uploads + " videos";
                result[1] = ""; //not used here                 
                result[2] = thumbUrl;                           
            }
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        //
    }
    return result;
}

/*** This function gets a number of today's uploads of the user ***/
private String getTodaysUploads (String username) {
    String result = null;
    String ytFeedUrl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=" + username + "&time=today&v=2";
    InputStream inStream = null;

    try {           
        inStream = OpenHttpConnection(ytFeedUrl);

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = db.parse(inStream);
        Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

        inStream.close();

        NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("feed");
        if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                Element entry = (Element) nl.item(i);
                Element title = (Element)entry.getElementsByTagName("openSearch:totalResults").item(0);                       

                result = title.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                result += " new today";
            }
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        //
    }
    return result;
}

private void displayData () {
    //Use vector instead of ArrayList for safe threading
    data = new Vector<RowData>();

    for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) { //Loop needs to be changed based on results
        try {
            rd = new RowData(i, title[i], detail.get(i), status.get(i));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        data.add(rd);
    }           

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter (this, R.layout.custom_list_item, R.id.title, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strUrl);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return inStream;
}

//This is temporary
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    CustomAdapter adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    RowData row = adapter.getItem(position);                
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(row.mTitle); 
    builder.setMessage(row.mDetail + " -> " + position );
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", null);
    builder.show();
}

//Private class RowData - holds details of CustomAdapter item
private class RowData {
    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;
    protected String mDetail;
    protected String mStatus;

    RowData (int id, String title, String detail, String status) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
        mDetail = detail;
        mStatus = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mId + " " + mTitle + " " + mDetail + " " + mStatus;
    }
}

//Custom Adapter for the custom list, overrides onView() method
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
        super (context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        TextView title = null;
        TextView detail = null;
        TextView status = null;
        ImageView image = null;
        RowData rowData = getItem(position);

        //Reuse existing row views
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        title = holder.getTitle();
        title.setText (rowData.mTitle);
        detail = holder.getDetail();
        detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);
        status = holder.getStatus();
        status.setText(rowData.mStatus);

        //add if statements here for colors

        image = holder.getImage();

        /**** This loads the pictures ****/
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        String imageUrl = imgurl.get(rowData.mId);
        Bitmap bm = LoadImage(imageUrl, bmOptions);
        image.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return convertView; 
    }

    //Load image from the URL
    private Bitmap LoadImage(String url, BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {
            inStream = OpenHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null, options);
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            ioex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }                       
}

/*** Wrapper for row data ***/
private class ViewHolder {
    private View mRow;
    private TextView title = null;
    private TextView detail = null;
    private TextView status = null;
    private ImageView image = null;

    public ViewHolder (View row) {
        mRow = row;
    }

    public TextView getTitle() {
        if (title == null) {
            title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
        return title;
    }

    public TextView getDetail() {
        if (detail == null) {
            detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        }
        return detail;
    }

    public TextView getStatus() {
        if (status == null) {
            status = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.status);
        }
        return status;
    }

    public ImageView getImage() {
        if (image == null) {
            image = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks a lot for any pointers.

Comment: Anything that takes a non-deterministic amount of time needs to be on a non-ui thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using standard java Thread to load the data from API in the background and created a separate class for loading images in separate threads as well. In case you're wondering it now looks like this, and seem to work fine.

Loading the data:

```
public void onCreate(...) {
    //...

    mHandler = new Handler();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(VodsActivity.this, "","Loading. Please wait...", true);
    getData.start();        
}

private Thread getData = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            loadData();             
            mHandler.post(showData);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

private Runnable showData = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            displayData();
            dialog.dismiss();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Loading images (in CustomAdapter):

```
        String imageUrl = imgurl.get(rowData.mId); 
        final ImageView image = holder.getImage();

        //Reuse downloaded images or download new in separate thread                       
        image.setTag(imageUrl);
        Drawable cachedImage = imageLoader.loadDrawable(imageUrl, new ImageCallback() {
            public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl) {
                ImageView imageViewByTag = (ImageView) image.findViewWithTag(imageUrl);
                if (imageViewByTag != null) {
                    imageViewByTag.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                }
            }
        });
        image.setImageDrawable(cachedImage);
```

ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {
private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>> imageCache;
private static final String TAG = "ImageLoader";

public ImageLoader() {
    imageCache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Drawable>>();
}

//Loads image from the cache if it exists or launches new thread to download it
public Drawable loadDrawable(final String imageUrl, final ImageCallback imageCallback) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadDrawable(" + imageUrl  + ")");
    if (imageCache.containsKey(imageUrl)) {
        SoftReference<Drawable> softReference = imageCache.get(imageUrl);
        Drawable drawable = softReference.get();
        if (drawable != null) {
            return drawable;
        }
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            imageCallback.imageLoaded((Drawable) message.obj, imageUrl);
        }
    };
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = loadImageFromUrl(imageUrl);
            imageCache.put(imageUrl, new SoftReference<Drawable>(drawable));
            Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, drawable);
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }.start();
    return null;
}

//Downloads image from the url
public static Drawable loadImageFromUrl(String url) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadImageFromUrl(" + url  + ")");
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new URL(url).openStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src");
}

public interface ImageCallback {
    public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl);
}
}
```

Comment: If you find this project grows, I would highly recommend the Volley library as well. It manages things like caching and retrying failed downloads, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  This will let you background your long-running processes while showing the UI.

Also, you can find good/official tutorial on Android threading [here.](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've read the basics. I'm just having a problem applying them in my code. The thing is that even if I run some parts of the code in separate threads the UI still does not show up until all the data is downloaded and progress dialog doesn't show at all. I managed to make it work in a simpler class displaying downloaded data in a TextView, but I can't achieve the same with a ListView.

Comment: You could try out `Service` if the AsyncTask isn't working for you. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html